# Moving <li> to another <ul> conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which may have many buttons and apps so for example i want when my menu has more than 5 "li" the hidden more menu appears and take from that five 2 or 3 so my menu will always have 5 "li" in it

```
With only 5 <li>:
<ul class='mymenu'>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li style="display:none;">More Button</li>
                 <ul>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                 </ul>
</ul>

When my menu have for example 8 <li>:
<ul class='list1'>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>More Button</li>
                 <ul>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                 </ul>
</ul>
```

So when my menu has 5 li the more menu will be still hidden but when it has more than 5 li the more menu will appear and will take from the li to make the while menu contains 5 li

Comment: Maybe you should google a little and try some code before asking here. Good luck. One hint: using JQuery shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: Start by fixing the invalid markup.

Comment: `$('.mymenu li:gt(4)').appendTo('ul.more');`

Comment: How are you building the menus? Is it static HTML or with something like PHP / Rails?

Comment: static html and adeneo it didnt work :(

Comment: and for others i am asking here to leanr from you if cant answer it for me dont write comments that are not helping

Comment: @AbdallahAbdalaziz : this community is for solving problems, not *teaching* web-tec....may be fixing up markup and doing some google will help you get started...your question should have been -1'ed as it doesn't even tells what **problem you are having in your code**, but good will stooped me....fix code,then ask...cheers!! :)

Comment: i am asking about what i have to do to make this work.

Comment: The first thing you have to do is correct the errors. This is invalid HTML, so it won't work the same in all browsers: different browsers have different error recovery! Then edit this question and post the new HTML in.